# Merge sorting days of the week

Tags: c#, mergesort

I have an object array (stockArray) that has string property that stores the days of the week. I have done a merge sort algorithm to sort these in order of the days of the week and not in alphabetical order. I have done this by converting the days into numbers and storing these in a double[] array:

```
string[] daysArray = new string[5] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

for (int i = 0; i < stockArray.Length; i++) //stockarray is the object array
{
    for (int j = 0; j < daysArray.Length; j++)
    {
         if (daysArray[j] == stockArray[i].day) 
         {
              sortArray[i] = j;
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

I then perform the merge sort and now I want to output the values, that have now been sorted, back into the days of the week format (i.e. "Monday", "Tuesday" etc), and also  match up the correct days of the week with the other properties in the object array (stockArray)

```
string day = "";
int m = 0;

while (m < stockArray.Length)
{
    foreach (double a in sortArray)
    {
        if (a == 0)                      
           day = "Monday";       
        else if (a == 1)
           day = "Tuesday";
        else if (a == 2)
           day = "Wednesday";
        else if (a == 3)
           day = "Thursday";
        else if (a == 4)
           day = "Friday";

        if (day == stockArray[m].day)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].date);
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].day);
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].open);
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].close);
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].difference);
           Console.WriteLine(stockArray[m].volume);
           Console.WriteLine("");

        }
        m++;                       
    }
 }                
 Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem with this code is that it outputs 31 out of the 144 days that are in the stockArray. I have checked the merge sort algorithm code and that seems to be working perfectly so the error seems to be in the while and foreach loop. It doesn't crash - just simply doesn't output all the elements. So if anyone could help me find the error in this code it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
class Stock
{
    public int Value;
    public string Day;
}

Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("Monday", 0);
dic.Add("Tuesday", 1);
dic.Add("Wednesday", 2);
dic.Add("Thursday", 3);
dic.Add("Friday", 4);

var stocks = new Stock[]
    {
        new Stock { Day = "Tuesday", Value= 10 },
        new Stock { Day = "Monday", Value= 5 },
    };

// result here
var result = stocks.OrderBy(f => dic[f.Day]).ToArray();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Day);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this, it spams the whole console window and it doesn't output in order of the days and the properties haven't matched up properly as they are duplicated. E.G:  http://puu.sh/hdN4T/0bc1d475dd.png
It does do all the days just spams and duplicates everything and they're not in the correct order

Comment: the main idea is you want to sort stockArray by Day of week?

Comment: yeah thats what im trying to do, all the other properties need to be arranged and displayed in respect to the days being sorted too

Comment: what does the value variable represent?

Comment: The rest of the object you're trying to sort.  In your case, date, day, open, close...